# Diagnose 'sh: 1: Bad substitution' from /bin/sh -exc

Tags: 18.04, sh, dash-shell

I've been trying to compile some ocaml packages and keep running into some errors of the form  `sh: 1: Bad substitution` (exit code 2), eg.

```
/bin/sh -exc echo | m4
/bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

But, `/bin/sh -ec echo | m4` has no error.  It seems that any command with both `-e` and `-x` flags passed to `/bin/sh` (/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash) results in this error.  Is this the expected behaviour, because I can't see anything to that effect in the manual, and I can't remember ever having this happen before.

EDIT: actually I see the error with any `/bin/sh -xc` command, regardless of `-e`

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem.  In my ~/.bashrc I set

```
export PS4='+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'
```

Which the dash manual says gets output before every trace line when `-x` is set. Exporting `PS4` without bashisms solves the problem.

I hadn't been expecting my `~/.bashrc` to be read at all in this case, but since `bash` is being used to execute `/bin/sh` I assume those variables are being seen by `dash` as well, annoyingly.

Comment: It's being seen by the child shell because you're exporting it: `PS1` thru `PS4` should really be plain shell variables (not exported) for exactly the reason you have just discovered i.e. that they are not portable between shells

Comment: @steeldriver yea, that was a frustating bug that caused me to make my entire config posix compliant before realizing this.  Not exporting `PS4` seems like a bummer, though, when debugging.  I was thinking about asking a follow-up about that

Comment: So why does running /bin/sh source bashrc ?have you symlinked /bin/sh to /bin/bash instead of /bin/dash ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy no, it's because I use bash as my default shell and was running build scripts from it